# Why when creating new enemy each enemy is missing the Rigidbody even if there is a Rigidbody in the prefab and the clone insatiate failed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurretTargeting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject targetPrefab;
    public float targetSpawnRadius = 50f;
    public float targetSpeed = 10f;
    public float targetAttackChance = 0.1f;
    public float targetAttackHeight = 10f;
    public float targetAttackWaveFrequency = 1f;
    public float targetAttackWaveAmplitude = 5f;

    private List<Transform> targets = new List<Transform>();

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnTargets());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnTargets()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Vector2 randomCircle = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * targetSpawnRadius;
            Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(randomCircle.x, 0f, randomCircle.y);
            GameObject target = Instantiate(targetPrefab, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            targets.Add(target.transform);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, 3f));
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Transform target in targets)
        {
            Vector3 direction = transform.position - target.position;
            float distance = direction.magnitude;
            if (distance > targetAttackHeight && Random.value < targetAttackChance)
            {
                StartCoroutine(AttackTarget(target));
            }
            else
            {
                target.Translate(direction.normalized * targetSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AttackTarget(Transform target)
    {
        float time = 0f;
        Vector3 startPosition = target.position;
        while (time < targetAttackWaveFrequency)
        {
            time += Time.deltaTime;
            float wave = Mathf.Sin(time * Mathf.PI * 2f / targetAttackWaveFrequency) * targetAttackWaveAmplitude;
            target.position = startPosition + Vector3.up * wave;
            yield return null;
        }
        target.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

when using a breakpoint after this line:

```
GameObject target = Instantiate(targetPrefab, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

and then moving the mouse over target I see the message:

Instantiate failed because the clone was destroyed during creation. This can happen if DestroyImmediate is called in MonoBehaviour.Awake.

and also

The Object you want to instantiate is null.

but i see the object Instantiated but without rigidbody attached to it.

Comment: sounds like your assigned prefab was already in game so died